# UIActivityIndicator в tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, activityindicator

У меня есть `tableView`. Если я нажимаю на ячейку `UIActivityIndicator` начинает анимацию. Но если я прокручиваю `tableView`, то индикатор исчезает. Как это исправить?

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryView = spinner;
[spinner startAnimating];
```

**UPD**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (indexPath.row == 1){
if (!fileExists) {
    [_spinner startAnimating];
}
if (fileExists) {
    [_spinner stopAnimating];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
 }
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 if (!fileExists) {
_spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
                                                         _spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
                                                         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
                                                         cell.accessoryView = _spinner;
                                                         [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryView = _spinner;
                                                         [_spinner startAnimating];
if (fileExists) {
[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
}
}
```

Comment: Прокручиваете за пределы видимости? Тогда все правильно. Вам необходимо запоминать состояние для ячейки и восстанавливать в cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Можете объяснить как это в коде сделать? Как ни пытался не получается

Comment: У Вас в `cellForRowAtIndexPath` условие нужно исправить. Если файл существует - показать галочку, если нет и загрузка - показывать индикатор.

Comment: Добавил обновленный код в вопрос. Но галочка при скроллинге так и не показывается.

Comment: ну так нужно убрать вью индикатора. Попробуйте `if (fileExists) {
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна из реализаций базово. В модели добавляете поле, к примеру, `BOOL isCellIndicatorActive`.

При условии когда необходим индикатор устанавливаете ему `YES` и делаете релоад нужной ячейки.

А вот в `cellForRowAtIndexPath` прописываете:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Configure the cell...
    if(_model.isCellIndicatorActive) {
        UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        spinner.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
        cell.accessoryView = spinner;
        [spinner startAnimating];
    }
    return cell;
}
```